# iPhone unix file access

Tags: iphone, file, permissions

When I use:

```
int fd = open(fileNameWitPath, O_CREAT | O_RDWR);
```

in the device simulator all is right.
But physical device return **fd = -1** and **errno = 0x0d (13), permission denied.**

The destination path is the application sandbox Documents or tmp path.

Is this possible to read & write files on iPhone, in the application private area, by Unix function without jailbreak?

Comment: you can access files in your application's sandbox (e.g. Documents folder). how are you getting `fileNameWitPath`? to get the Documents directory you need to do: `NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); NSString *docPath = [paths  objectAtIndex:0];`  for the temp dir: `NSTemporaryDirectory()` is an NSString with the path to tmp

Comment: "how are you getting..." : NSArray *dp = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  NSString *path = [dp objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: Please re-read my answer I've rewritten it.  The code works now.

Answer (score 2):

It should work OK but you have to remember that the iOS Simulator uses different filesystem than a real device. And the fact that you can only READ files from the bundle, not WRITE, and you try to open with read\write permission. please check the value of *fileNameWitPath*

The right way to get the document directory is:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

You should use

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
[fileManager createFileAtPath: contents: attributes:]
```

instead of

```
int fd = open(fileNameWitPath, O_CREAT | O_RDWR);
```

Comment: I think it's a case of "You must use" instead of "You can also use" :P

Comment: After 2 days of fight with file access my conclusion is: posix io functions under device, in ".../Documents/" folder, work bad. File is created but open() or creat() always return descriptor -1 with errno 0x0d. iPhone is very strange for me:) That work under symbian, android etc. but not work under iOS. Now I use fileManager and it's OK.

Answer (score 2):

Skippy's comment regarding the missing third parameter is the correct issue at hand here.

Without the third parameter, open(...) will work the first time, and fail with -1 and EACCES on subsequent runs because the app created the file the first time, but no longer has permission to access the file.  (If you are recompiling and testing on device, and seeing the error, it's because you need to delete the app which deletes the incorrectly-permissioned file.)

Answer (score 0):

**Compleat rewrite of answer **

The following code works:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    NSArray *dp = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *path = [dp objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileNameWithPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",path,@"fileName.txt"];
    int fd = open([fileNameWithPath UTF8String], O_CREAT | O_RDWR);

    NSLog(@"Open %@ for writing returned %d",fileNameWithPath,fd);

    return YES;
}
```

Debug output:

```
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 1
(gdb) n
30      NSLog(@"Open %@ for writing returned %d",fileNameWithPath,fd);
(gdb) n
2012-01-20 11:01:23.161 FOpen[6535:707] Open /var/mobile/Applications/AF7EA358-E4AA-491F-AEA1-83080F2749E5/Documents/fileName.txt for writing returned 6
32      return YES;
```

The key is that you must pass the c function 'open' a c style string, e.g. `[fileNameWithPath UTF8String]`.  If you are using ARC you may have to do a bit more to get the compiler happy, I can't confirm that though.

Comment: So I use the same way to get the path, but result of the open() ora creat() is always -1 with errno 0x0d. The same result is for the tmp path: NSString *path = NSTemporaryDirectory(); And one thing - in XCode Organizer, Applications (for my device) and "Data files in sandbox" - the file exist, but with lenght = 0B.

Comment: path on device, where I probe write file: /var/mobile/Applications/7FF29BC7-B6D1-41CF-8621-CC6DFEEEEF045/Documents

Comment: "...the file exist, but with lenght = 0B..." it means that open() create the file, but not return descriptor, says "access denied". I completly don't understand it.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll have a quick look myself in a dummy app.

Comment: I get the same output:

`2012-01-20 10:45:41.830 FOpen[6513:707] Open /var/mobile/Applications/AF7EA358-E4AA-491F-AEA1-83080F2749E5/Documents/fileName.txt for writing returned -1`

I would accept for now that behaviour has changed so I'd probably accept Oded's answer.

Comment: Answer rewritten.  You must use UTF8String

Answer (score 0):

I was write:

```
int fd = open(fileNameWithPath, O_CREAT | O_RDWR);
```

But "**Call to 'open' requires third argument when the 'O_CREAT' is set**".
The line of the code must be (for RW permissions):

```
 int fd = open(fileNameWithPath, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0x0666);
```

and this work fine.

[edit]
I was write:

```
int fd = open(fileNameWithPath, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0x0666);
```

this is error, umask must be 666 but octal, not hex:

```
int fd = open(fileNameWithPath, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 00666);
```